# How to customize Unity Dependency injection to select a different constructor as an extension

Tags: unity-container

I am not in control of the registration of dependencies of my unity container and want to build an extension that allows me to select a different constructor then the default one.

So how do i do this in a builder strategy like below?

```
public sealed class CustomBuilderStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
    private readonly CustomBuildExtension extension;

    public CustomBuilderStrategy(CustomBuildExtension extension)
    {
        this.extension = extension;
    }


   public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   {
   //Check if type has more than one constructor
   // select a random constructor and build the object. (I will write my own custom code then if this works.

       base.PreBuildUp(context);
   }

    public override void PostTearDown(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        base.PostTearDown(context);
    }

    public override void PostBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        base.PostBuildUp(context);
    }

    public override void PreTearDown(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        base.PreTearDown(context);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find some data regarding to overriding the object creation at:
https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/unity-part-10-custom-build-strategies

To get information about the constructors for a given type you can use reflection
typeof(type).GetConstructors()